# As an international student in France, can I apply for UK's tier-4 Visa (for a PhD) from Paris?

Tags: france, student-visa, uk-visa

I have received a PhD offer from an English university. I am currently living in France with a student residence permit (*titre de séjour étudiant*). My residence permit expired on August 2020 but I have renewed it twice since then (twice because of Covid-19 related reasons) and currently I have a receipt of a residence permit (*récépissé de demande de carte de séjour*) that is valid for 3 months until January 2021 (while waiting for the new residence permit to be issued).

My home country (Algeria) is border-closed due to Covid-19. I want to know whether it is possible for me to apply for UK's tier-4 Visa from Paris using my current receipt of the residence permit (*récépissé de demande de carte de séjour*)?

Comment: The UK's French Embassy's webpage contains this page: https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english about contacting UKVI, either by telephone or email. Have you considered asking UKVI?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidSupportsMonica. I will consider contacting them on that online form.